# Making a website accessible by one or two IP's

Tags: php, ip

Well, I have made a portal made for my client and it is all coded in custom php. Now Client have told me to make it only accessible to two IP that is to be used within the company intranet.

well we have a shared hosting for that portal.
Is is possible to make it accessible to one ip only ?

and how ? like if there is any code to be added?

Regards

Comment: Only if the client's IP is sent to the server (i.e. no proxy server or NAT is in place).

Comment: If you're not hosting behind a proxy/load balancer then `$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']` contains the remote IP . Load balancers tend to forward this but you need to refer to your proxy/load balancer to find out how.

Comment: Bear in mind that any forwarded client IP (in `X-Forwarded-For` etc) can be easily spoofed.

Comment: And... `X-Forwarded-For` is not always used.

Comment: as @iainn says. If you are behind a proxy you need to ensure `$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']` is the real proxy IP before deciding whether to trust forwarded headers.

Comment: Client have a static ip .. the portal is simply hosted on godaddy shared hosting .. they just wanted it accessible by that static ip ....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use the $_SERVER global variable, like this:

```
if ($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] == '127.0.0.1') {
  // restrict
}
```

Good alternative is the session filter: http://php.net/manual/en/session.examples.basic.php

You can also use cookies: 
http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.setcookie.php

Answer (score 1):

There are ways to whitelist IP's from inside your webhost cPanel.. If you wanted to do this with PHP, you would need to add this before anything else initiates in your PHP.

```
$whitelist = array('192.0.0.1', '192.0.0.2', etc);
if(!in_array($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'], $whitelist)){
    header('location:http://google.com');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

While PHP is pretty cool, why not leave security to things actually designed for security?  Create a .htaccess file and put...

```
order deny,allow
deny from all
allow from xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
allow from xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
```

Where xxx = the IPs you want to allow